# Changing the colour for a specific hyperlink in html5/CSS

Tags: css, html, colors

I'm really sorry if this is basic stuff- I'm new to html and style sheets and I've googled around for a while, but so far haven't found an answer to my question: I'm writing a single-page website where the subsections have different background colours and I have specified the colours for a, a.hover and so forth in my style sheet, eg.

```html
a { color: #48A3A6; text-decoration: none;}
```

However For one of the subsections I need my hyperlink to have a different font colour. How can I achieve this? Specifying a different text colour doesn't seem to work, as it's not text and I don't want to change the hyperlink colour for the entire webpage.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your HTML and explain more clearly what you want?

Comment: a.foo {color: red;} <a class="foo" href="#">I'm red</a>

Comment: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: Such a simple solution, thanks, this worked shaunsantacruz and MelanciaUK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a class or an id to your  tag and than crate a [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for it in your css. You can also do achieve that with inline style but it is not a best practice:
class:

HTML:

```
<a class="my-class">Link</a>
<a id="my-id">Link</a>
<a style="color:#000;">Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class{
    color:#000;
}
#my-id{
    color:#000;
}
```

will all achieve the same result

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing out the different options! I'll look into it a bit more to see what's neatest for future reference. :)